# Ag grid SideBar with custom Tool Panel not showing

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I was following a tutorial on how to setup a side bar with custom tool panel in angular app.

For some reason, it is not showing.

This is ag grid definition:

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
[sideBar]="sideBar"
[icons]="icons"
[frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

This is side bar definition inside constructor:

```
    this.sideBar = {
      toolPanels: [
        {
          id: 'customStats',
          labelDefault: 'Custom Stats',
          labelKey: 'customStats',
          iconKey: 'custom-stats',
          toolPanel: 'customStats',
        }
      ],
      defaultToolPanel: 'customStats',
    };
    this.frameworkComponents = { customStats: SumToolPanel };
```

The custom tool panel is copy/paste from [dookumentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-tool-panel/#example-custom-stats-tool-panel-component)

i have named it `SumToolPanel`. Also, i have noticed that it's not being called, I've placed break point in every function of `SumToolPanel`

this is in app.module.ts

```
imports: [
 ...
  imports: [
     AgGridModule.withComponents([SumToolPanel])
  ]
...
]
```

Comment: The plunkr that you posted is empty. Please post an updated one.

Comment: i have updated it. i have link to original documentation example

Comment: i just got error in console ag-grid-community.cjs.js:33085 AG Grid: sideBar is not loaded